# like function mixed with number range

Tags: sql

how can i mix string and numbers in a like function whereas Professor 1-12

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. what have you tried yourself so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please edit your question to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like as '%Professor%1%12%'. Hope this answers your question.
If not please elaborate your question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).